# Outlook Application.FileDialog not found

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing a VBA macro for Outlook and the Application.FileDialog method is not available.

The intent is for the user to select a folder - not an Outlook email folder, but a file system directory folder.

Here are the references I have enabled:

- Visual Basic for Applications Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library  OLE Automation Microsoft Forms
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation Microsoft Forms Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Run-time
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure that's an Excel reference (Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library on my PC).  Do you just want to select a file?

Comment: I want the user to be able to select a folder.

Comment: For FileDialog method, you will need to use ms-word or Excel reference

Comment: Modified the question to clarify I want a file system directory folder, not an outlook email folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Outlook doesn't support the FileDialog object. Here's a workaround:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = xlApp.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim selectedItem As Variant

If fd.Show = -1 Then
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        Debug.Print selectedItem
    Next
End If

Set fd = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Perfect!

I only work in VBA a day or two every 5 years and I hadn't yet puzzled out how to create the Excel or Word application yet.  Thanks for saving me hours!

Comment: Nice, simple workaround.  But one detail to note is that you don't actually have to set the xlApp object's Visible property to False because that is its default state.

Comment: For anyone using this method - you'll probably very quickly realize that the `FilePicker` opens behind all other windows and is difficult to find (it looks like Outlook is frozen). After a lot of searching, the fix is actually pretty simple. You'll need something like `Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal win As LongPtr) As LongPtr` - see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview) and then before `fd.Show` just add `SetForegroundWindow (xlApp.hWnd)`

Answer (score 5):

*Here is another workaround that I have used*

```
Option Explicit
' For Outlook 2010.
#If VBA7 Then
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As LongPtr

    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                                 ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

' For the previous version of Outlook 2010.
#Else
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As Long

    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                                 ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
'
' Windows desktop -
' the virtual folder that is the root of the namespace.
Private Const CSIDL_DESKTOP = &H0

' Only return file system directories.
' If user selects folders that are not part of the file system,
' then OK button is grayed.
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1

' Do not include network folders below
' the domain level in the dialog box's tree view control.
Private Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = &H2

Public Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim blnIsEnd As Boolean

    blnIsEnd = False

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( _
                lHwnd, "Please Select Folder to:", _
                BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, CSIDL_DESKTOP)


    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        strFolderPath = ""
        blnIsEnd = True
        GoTo PROC_EXIT
    Else
        strFolderPath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    If blnIsEnd Then End
End Sub

Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function
```

Comment: Outlook 365 and it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This selects a folder. How do select a file?